# How to split a number into individual digits in c#?

Tags: c#, string

Say I have 12345.

I'd like individual items for each number. A String would do or even an individual number.

Does the .Split method have an overload for this?

Answer (score 69):

I'd use modulus and a loop.

```
int[] GetIntArray(int num)
{
    List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
    while(num > 0)
    {
        listOfInts.Add(num % 10);
        num = num / 10;
    }
    listOfInts.Reverse();
    return listOfInts.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way to do it. But it will exclude the starting zero i.e. **0**123. In case I require starting **0** as well. How to go about it?

Comment: @SaimMehmood 0123 is not a number

Comment: 0 is a number but it will be excluded :) do...while would do the trick

Comment: @Tommy If required, at the top I would add `if(num == 0) { return new int[] {0}; }` or something similar if the development team standards are for 1 return statement etc etc. In my original post I said I wasn't a fan of strings... I'm not a fan of do...whiles either...

Comment: @Biff MaGriff whatever would make it work. Except of strings. Not a fan too.

Comment: Love the simplicity.

Answer (score 35):

Something like this will work, using Linq:

```
string result = "12345"
var intList = result.Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString()));
```

This will give you an IEnumerable list of ints.

If you want an IEnumerable of strings:

```
var intList = result.Select(digit => digit.ToString());
```

or if you want a List of strings:

```
var intList = result.ToList();
```

Comment: .Parse(.ToString)!? Sense. It makes none.

Comment: @Randy, did you modify your answer?  It was correct before, now it's wrong.  This will return an `IEnumerable` of `string`.  (I just changed it back)

Comment: @dtb, what is the confusion?  `digit` is a `char`, and `int.Parse` takes a `string`.  Hence: `digit.ToString()`.

Comment: @Kirk - Thank you. I actually wasn't sure what he wanted, an IEnumerable of strings or ints.

Comment: @Randy, ah, maybe.  You can change it back again, just make sure the "This will give you an IEnumerable list of xxx" is correct. ;)

Comment: @Kirk - Right, thank you. I've actually included both now.

Comment: @Kirk: Why would one ever convert something to string, just to parse it back to another data type, instead of converting the value directly? [Char.GetNumericValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx)

Comment: @dtb, there's a very good reason for it.  I didn't know `char.GetNumericValue` existed. ;)   Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: As @dtb said, slightly better solution is: `"12345".Select(c => (int) Char.GetNumericValue(c))`. Casting to int is needed due to double result of `GetNumericValue`.

Answer (score 11):

Well, a string is an IEnumerable and also implements an indexer, so you can iterate through it or reference each character in the string by index.

The fastest way to get what you want is probably the ToCharArray() method of a String:

```
var myString = "12345";

var charArray = myString.ToCharArray(); //{'1','2','3','4','5'}
```

You can then convert each Char to a string, or parse them into bytes or integers. Here's a Linq-y way to do that:

```
byte[] byteArray = myString.ToCharArray().Select(c=>byte.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

A little more performant if you're using ASCII/Unicode strings:

```
byte[] byteArray = myString.ToCharArray().Select(c=>(byte)c - 30).ToArray();
```

That code will only work if you're SURE that each element is a number; otherisw the parsing will throw an exception. A simple Regex that will verify this is true is "^\d+$" (matches a full string consisting of one or more digit characters), used in the Regex.IsMatch() static method.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do:

```
"123456".Select(q => new string(q,1)).ToArray();
```

to have an enumerable of integers, as per comment request, you can:

```
"123456".Select(q => int.Parse(new string(q,1))).ToArray();
```

It is a little weak since it assumes the string actually contains numbers.

Comment: Doesn't return something of `IEnumerable<int>` (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that might help you out.  Strings can be treated as an array of characters

```
string numbers = "12345";
int[] intArray = new int[numbers.Length];
for (int i=0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
   intArray[i] = int.Parse(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: The second-to-last line gives an error. Don't include `[i]` with the `numbers`.

Comment: int.Parse not works for me, it resolves cannot convert from 'char' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan<char>'

Comment: i use this instead and it works

   resValue[i] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(value.ToString()[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Substring and Join methods are usable for this statement.

```
string no = "12345";
string [] numberArray = new string[no.Length];
int counter = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < no.Length; i++)
   {
     numberArray[i] = no.Substring(counter, 1); // 1 is split length
     counter++;
   }

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numberArray)); //output >>> 0 1 2 3 4 5
```