# Why do I get a compile error when calling string.Select in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, select

In a different question ([How to split a number into individual digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808612/how-to-split-a-number-into-individual-digits)), they call the `Select` method on a string. [This site](http://www.dotnetperls.com/select) also suggests that it is possible.

However, when I try to do this using the code samples found in either of those places, I get a compile error. What could be causing this, and how can I use the `Select` method on a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add a reference `system.core.dll`

1.In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project node and click Add Reference.

2.In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.

3.On .NET tab Select `System.Core`, then click OK.

And add `using System.Linq` on what the example you provided;

and make sure that youre project framework is 3.5 because it will not work on lower versions.

Regards

Comment: Wrong; that's LINQ to SQL.  You mean `System.Core.dll`.

Comment: How do I add a reference to system.core.dll

Answer (score 12):

This is a LINQ method.

To use it, you need to be using .Net 3.5 or later, have referenced `System.Core.dll`, and have `using System.Linq`.

Comment: How do I reference System.Core.dll?

Comment: Right-click the project, `Add Reference`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have included the `System.Linq` reference?

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yes I have "using System.Linq;"