# How can I store a string of numbers in a text file and read each number into an array index?

Tags: c#

If I have a text file with the string:
    100101101

I can read and store this by using the following code:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"writeText.txt");
```

How can I convert the string into separate numbers and add each number to an array index, do I need to separate each number with a comma? I was thinking I could iterate through the string and for each character convert to an integer and add to array, would this work?

Here is what i am trying:

```
        int[] arrSetup = new int[9];
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"writeText.txt");

        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            arrSetup[0] = Int32.Parse(c);

        }
```

Comment: Well, there are various steps there - splitting by commas, parsing integer, storing in an array... what have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a number into individual digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808612/how-to-split-a-number-into-individual-digits)

Comment: Are you wanting to store it in same format?  Are you looking to reverse then store it?  Group similar numbers?

Comment: I have edited my question to show my latest attempt. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data was like  this : `100101101`.. So Separate by Commas and then add that to integer array is not needed...

So just try like below, it will help you...

```
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"writeText.txt");
        int[] arr = new int[text.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(text[i].ToString());
        }
```

Now the integer array `arr[]` have the Values separately...

Comment: Excellent this worked perfectly! I will accept as answer once it allows me! Thank you for this, I was almost there! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help ,try it yourself :

```
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"writeText.txt");
        char[] arr = text.ToCharArray() ;
        int[] nums = {0};
        for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++)
           nums[a] = System.Convert.ToInt32(arr[a]);
```