# list of ints transform to array of integers

Tags: c#

I'm getting integeres to my controller as 123456 in one variable.

Now I want to transform each number to separated from other with comma between as array of numbers as `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`.

Comment: it's not duplicate cause I'm getting parameter as int instead of string.

Comment: Your title suggests you want to convert `List<int>` to `int[]`. Can you please rephrase your question to clearly state **exactly** what you have and what you want?

Comment: ... and the highest rated answer deals with an int.

Comment: `123456.ToString().Select(c => (int) Char.GetNumericValue(c))` (from linked answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var integers = "123456";
var enumOfInts = integers.ToCharArray().Select(x => Char.GetNumericValue(x));
```

Comment: +1 despite the fact that I hate LINQ, but your code looks cleaner ;)

Comment: @AlinaB. - what makes you hate linq?

Comment: That is not going to give what you want. It is going to print 49, 50, etc.

Comment: @AppDeveloper I don't know. Maybe I am to lazy to learn it ;)

Comment: its wrong , your array of int is : `{int[6]}
    [0]: 49
    [1]: 50
    [2]: 51
    [3]: 52
    [4]: 53
    [5]: 54`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not in front of a compiler right now. Should be fixed now

Comment: The char `'1'` is different from the int `1`. Either subtract 48 from the char value or use `Char.GetNumericValue(x)`

Comment: If you know `integers` only contains the digits 0 through 9, then `x-'0'` would be *much* faster than `int.Parse(x)`. Also, the `var` keyword is causing the extremely misleading situation where `arrayOfInts` is the name of an `IEnumerable<int>` that is definitely *not* an array.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int[] array = new int["123456".ToArray().Count()];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in "123456".ToArray())
            {
                array[i++] = int.Parse(item.ToString());
            }
```

or

```
   int[] array = "123456".ToArray().Select(data=>(int)data).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    string s = "1234567890";
    var lst = new List<int>();

    for (int n = 0; n < s.Length; n++)
    {
        int x;
        if (int.TryParse(s[n].ToString(), out x))
            lst.Add(x);
    }

    int[] arr = lst.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? -1 for a working solution sucks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting parameter as string then

The Linq Way :

```
string str_num = "123456"
var arrayOfInts = str_num.ToCharArray().Select(x => x - 48).ToArray();
```

for the above Linq expression it has been assumed that all character are between `48` & `57`

Non Linq Way :

```
int[] GetIntArray(string str_num)
{
    int num = Int32.Parse(str_num);
    List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
    while(num > 0)
    {
        listOfInts.Add(num % 10);
        num = num / 10;
    }
    listOfInts.Reverse();
    return listOfInts.ToArray();
}
```

Solution extended from : [How to split a number into individual digits in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808612/how-to-split-a-number-into-individual-digits)