# How to split a number into individual nos

Tags: c#

I have a `int number = 1782901998` whose Length is 10 numbers; I need to split them into 10 different strings. I tried the following code, but it does not give back any output; I need to assign the each number to a string.

```
string number = 7894;
char[] numberChars = number.ToString().ToCharArray();
int[] digits = new int[numberChars.length];

for(int i = 0; i < numberChars.length; i++) {

    digits[i] = (int)numberChars[i];

 }
```

This code only returns `57` in digits list.

Comment: This code fills an array of integers with the ASCII code for the characters '7', '8', '9', and '4' (55,56,57,52). (By the way it doesn't even compile)

Comment: Please explain, do you want an array of integers (as your code is doing now) or do you want an array of strings?

Comment: @Steve Can't tell why this is re-opened. Why do you think this not a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-an-int-into-an-array-of-ints-of-each-digit) which is also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808612/how-to-split-a-number-into-individual-digits-in-c). I mean after convert converting it to int OP can then convert it to string with the `ToString()` function....

Comment: Well, this is probably a **BorderlIne Duplicate** as [explained by Jeff here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) and I have chose to reopen following this point  _There's often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they're looking for_ However I agree that this is really _borderline_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your code fills the array with the ASCII code for the characters of the `number` variable. You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) like below:

```
int[] digits = number.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Or if you want to assign the each number to a string simply:

```
string[] digits = number.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: We also have `double[] digits = number.Select(char.GetNumericValue).ToArray();` or `int[] digits = number.Select(c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();`.