# How to convert int to List<int>

Tags: c#

I want an solution to convert an input int say 010 to list of int {0,1,0}.
Below is code I tried, works until 0 is encountered.

```
Int num = 010;
List<int> listOfInt = new List<int>();
While(num > 0)
listOfInt.Add(num%10);
num / = 10;
```

I just want to split entered int and convert it to list of int. LINQ is fine if that could be efficient!

Comment: LINQ does not deal with this

Comment: `010` can never be an int btw, `010` is `10` when represented as an integer, lead zeros are irrecoverable.

Comment: you probably missing `{` and `}`

Comment: If you want this code fixed, explain your problem very explicitly (what is _"works until 0 is encountered"_? Which 0? What do you expect to see, and what do you actually see?). If you just want any code that does this, see [How to split a number into individual digits in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808612/how-to-split-a-number-into-individual-digits-in-c).

Comment: You have to loop through string length and add each one

Comment: an Integer 010 will always be saved as 10. So if you want to save "010" you need a string

Comment: There is no difference between `010` and `10` either in computer arithmetic or real life. Zero is zero. If you want to convert the number to a specific string format and extract the characters,just do so: `ToString("000").Select(c=>c-48).ToList()`. The `c-48` takes advantage of the fact that characters are essentially ints, and digits start from 0 upwards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others already mentioned `010` is identical to `10` when having parsed as `int`. However you could have your number as string coming from a console-input for example.

```
string myNumber = "010";
```

This can be split on every character quite easy using LINQ:

```
var intList = myNumber.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString())).ToList();
```

As every character is internally an `int` where `'0'` equals `49` you have to convert every single character to a string before which is done by using `ToString`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:")
var input = Console.ReadLine();

List<int> result = input.Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between 010 and 10 either in computer arithmetic or real life. Zero is zero.

If you want to convert the number to a specific string format and extract the characters, perform the same steps as the statement:

```
10.ToString("000").Select(c=>c-48).ToList();
```

The result is a list with the numbers 0,1,0.

The expression `c-48` takes advantage of the fact that characters are essentially ints, and digits start from 0 upwards. So 48 is 0, 1 is 49 etc.

If the input is a string, eg `"10"` you'll have to pad it with 0s up to the desired length:

```
"10".PadLeft(3,'0').Select(c=>c-48).ToList()
```

The result will be `0,1,0` again.

If, after all, you only want to retrieve characters from a paddes string, you only need padding, as a String *is* an IEnumerable. You can copy the characters to an array with [String.ToCharArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) or to a List as before:

```
"10".PadLeft(3,'0').ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string num = "010";
List<int> listOfInt = new List<int>();
foreach(char item in num)
{
  listOfInt.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: No cast means you would get a list of int character codes

Comment: don't u need a conversion from char to int before adding it to list. iirc, there is no implicit conversion from `char` to `int`

Comment: Implicitly `(int)'1'` is 49

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString())     it works item.ToString() will give characters not ascii values

Comment: @andy or, since characters are integers, subtract 48. No allocations, conversions or parsing. `'1'-48` returns `1`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Or, even `item - '0'`. That way you avoid a magic number `48`.

Comment: @PCLuddite it's not a magic number. `0` *is* 48

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, but in my opinion it's more clear what you're trying to do if you subtract character `'0'` rather than integer `48`. I like many others do not have the ascii table memorized.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you'll also help give more evidence to your point that `char`s are promoted to integers by doing this. Otherwise the assumption could be made that `char` are promoted to integers only when one of the operand is an integer as well.