# Console.ReadLine().Contains Console.ReadLine()? why do i get false when the number is present in both?

Tags: c#

Could someone help me why do i get true only if the numbers are the same? I need to find out if the second input is in the first one. True/false

```
int[] firstNumber;
firstNumber = new int[10];
firstNumber[0] = 
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int secondNumber = 
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) ;

Console.WriteLine(firstNumber.Contains(secondNumber));
```

Edit. I need to get true for ex.:firstNumber 5214 and secondNumber 4

Comment: what problem are you having? How is your code not meeting your expectations?

Comment: `firstNumber` is an array.

Comment: Why an array does contain a number only if that number is the one that was put there?

Comment: "Could someone help me why do i get true only if the numbers are the same? I need to find out if the second input is in the first one." You only get true when they are the same because that's the only time the second number is in the array.

Comment: hmm. and some lead how can i get true for 5432(firstNum) and 3(secondNum)

Comment: instead of int[] use string

Comment: Using string instead of int will work, but I wonder if teacher expects to see some math manipulation here. Like trying to isolate every digit with math.

Comment: That's a question for your teacher, and we don't know what tools (like Linq) you can use to do that, but if you knew that a string was an array of characters, how would you `Parse` each character into an `int` and put them in the array? (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4808655/1081897) for one option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i get true for 5432(firstNum) and 3(secondNum)

Use strings instead of integers, which will use `string.Contains` instead of `Array.Contains`:

```
string firstNumber = Console.ReadLine();
string secondNumber = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(firstNumber.Contains(secondNumber));
```