# How to get sum of the cubes of its digits

Tags: c#, algorithm, integer, cube

First of all I want to know what it is even called; lets take an example a number

```
153
```

now let's cube all its digits:

```
(1 * 1 * 1) + (5 * 5 * 5) + (3 * 3 * 3) == 153
```

if the output is `153`, what exactly is this thing called. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say now. I also want to implement the same thing in code without using any predefined methods in **C#**

How can I do that?

Please note that the input number can be *dynamic* and not hard coded like `153` as example

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: If you haven't started yet, the first thing I can think of is to split your input into digits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808612/how-to-split-a-number-into-individual-digits-in-c can help (dupe target)

Comment: yes i dont even know what that number is it even called thats why im asking it like this

Comment: If this scenario has a name then it is a recreational maths question not a programming one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/643456/914

Comment: `1, 153, 370, 371, 407` oeis A046197 https://oeis.org/A046197

Comment: okay im storing each digits from the input into a List , now what should i do now ?

Comment: ??? What do you think you do., based on the question?  You cube the digits, add them, and compare to the original number.

Comment: cube the digits and then add them and then compare it to the orignl

Comment: By the way, your title is wrong -- you want the "sum of the cubes of its digits", not the "sum of the digits of its cube", which would be another sequence entirely.

Comment: And for those who are curious, this is called "an Armstrong number".  https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please note that the sequence is *finite*: if we have `5` digits number, the maximum sum of digits cubed can be

```
99999 -> 5 * 9**3 == 3645 (max possible sum) < 10000 (min possible number)
```

Using *calculus* you can prove that sum of digits cubed grows slower than number itself (let me omit the proof); so if number has `5` or more digits it can't be the number we are looking for.

So far so good, we should check numbers from `1` to `10000` only.

**Code:** (please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N9d0dA) yourself)

```
private static IEnumerable<int> A046197() {
  for (int number = 1; number < 10000; ++number) {
    int s = 0;
        
    for (int n = number; n > 0; n /= 10) {
      int d = n % 10;

      s += d * d * d;
    }

    if (number == s)
      yield return number;
  }
}
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", A046197()));
```

**Output:**

```
1, 153, 370, 371, 407
```

Note, that these numbers are [A046197](https://oeis.org/A046197) sequence in oeis where you can find details.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a beginner in C#, so if you can add another section after the main solution ,where you explain it with just static input and long but simple code, it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: i didnt get this thing IEnumerable<int> A046197()

Comment: That just lets it return a sequence of numbers, one at a time using yield, instead of (for example) building up an array and returning the array.  And please don't ask him to turn this into a complete program for you.  You are required to do SOME of the work here.